# Trim Job has encountered a problem in STS

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In STS, when I click   Clear console  button , below message  appear

An internal error has occurred.
class org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ansi.participants.AnsiPosition cannot be cast to class mnita.ansiconsole.participants.AnsiPosition (org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ansi.participants.AnsiPosition is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6cddcab6; mnita.ansiconsole.participants.AnsiPosition is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @a58f9a6)

Despite various attempts, the problem is not resolved

I don't want that error message to appear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling de Ansi Console plugin worked for me. I got it twice, one standalone and one as dependency of M2E Chromatic.

Answer (score 0):

In my case as well this got resolved when I removed both "ANSI Escape in Console" and "m2e-chromatic" plugins from eclipe-marketplace.
[Screenshot for the plugins in eclipse-market place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAIWB.png)